# How to break SQL command in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

stuck in trouble. I have a txt-file, which save SQL Commands, when Internet Connection is disabled. 
[image]

The fact is that in my database table there is a primary key marked on the date column. And sometimes SQL Command is corrupted( like on picture) and the SQL command loops on a specific date. It must be done so that if he cannot send a command, skip it and move on to the next command.

The part of my code, which send strings as SQL Commands :

```
If _DB.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    Dim Massiv() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Components\Data.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
                    For Each element In Massiv

                        _SQLcommandFromFiles = New SqlCommand(element, _DC)
                        _SQLcommandFromFiles.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Next
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your code. As you have chosen not to share the relevant code with us, we can't possibly tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Did you analyse where and why this crippled commands are produced? In first place you should not find a solution to handle crippled commands, instead you should find a solution that avoids producing crippled commands at all. ((and because i love metaphors) Actual you asked for a automated tire hole patching, instead of avoiding driving thru nails at all.)

Comment: @Horitsu Thank you for responding. I guessed that SQL Command write wrong SQLCommand, without my data, into my txt file,  when my connection to database is reconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround your code with try catch block like this

```
If _DB.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    Dim Massiv() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Components\Data.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
                    For Each element In Massiv
                         Try
                            _SQLcommandFromFiles = New SqlCommand(element, _DC)
                            _SQLcommandFromFiles.ExecuteNonQuery()
                         Catch ex As Exception

                         End Try
                    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open your file then read line by line and use 'try catch' for the execution of your query.

Comment: Welcome to the community :) Make sure you include as much details as possible or code snapshots before answering !